# Building a class schedule program?

Tags: software-design

My school still puts schedules together by hand. My teacher had an idea for me to make a program that does it automatically. My question is, does anyone know where I should start?

Comment: I understand nothing from your question !

Comment: Designing the work flow, designing the interface, writing some code... Those would be good places to start.

Comment: What languages do you know?  Are you making a program for just your class or the entire school?

Comment: I was wondering if anyone has any idea on which programming language I should use, how would I approach the user interface, etc.

Comment: @cjayem13  I know html, css, javascript, and ruby. It would be for the whole school

Comment: Whatever you know best.

Comment: @user4042790: I'm afraid this is far too broad for a Stack Overflow question.  We're happy to help answer specific questions about your implementation for any code you end up writing, but we don't provide tutorials and guidance for an entire project.

Comment: @David im sorry I just needed to know if anyone had ideas where to start. I've never asked a stack overflow question and didn't really know how to word it.

Comment: @user4042790 Check out http://stackoverflow.com/tour  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice? for info on how to post

Comment: Not a problem.  Did you get the information you needed for your question?  In school I was instructed make a pseudo program (an outline) of what I want to accomplish.  That might be a good place to start.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try checking out sites below.  Sorry but your question is very vague and unclear.
http://www.wikihow.com/Start-Learning-to-Program
http://www.wikihow.com/Write-Pseudocode